# What is data is submitted to Google when using google maps?

Tags: google-maps

I have been asked by a client to map data, but the client does not what any other data besides addresses for geocoding to be sent to another server. Does the Google maps API submit other data besides addresses and latitude/longitude to Google?

For example, I would not want the "dealerInfo" node to be submitted to Google in the following XML used for a map on [http://www.coastalbendchevydealers.com/][1] .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<markers>
    <!-- Neessen Automotive -->
    <marker lat="27.5380258" lng="-97.8547257" dealer="Neessen Automotive">
    <dealerInfo><![CDATA[
        <table border="0" class="infoWindow">
            <tr><td rowspan="5" width="155" align="left"><img src="images/chevydealer.jpg" width="150" height="113"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td align="left"><strong>Neessen Automotive</strong></td></tr>
            <tr><td align="left">2007 S. US Highway 77 Bypass<br>Kingsville, Texas</td></tr>
            <tr><td align="left">361-592-2668</td></tr>
            <tr><td align="left"><a href="http://www.neessenautomotive.com" target="_blank">www.neessenautomotive.com</a></td></tr>
        </table>
    ]]></dealerInfo>
    </marker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind Google is providing this as a free service, if you are concerned over data sharing then look into the premium licensing (10K / year)

From Google's Privacy Policy:

> 11. Licenses from You to Google.
>
> 11.1 Content License. **Google claims no ownership over Your Content**, and You
>   retain copyright and any other rights
>   you already hold in Your Content. **By
>   submitting, posting or displaying Your
>   Content in the Service, you give
>   Google a perpetual, irrevocable,
>   worldwide, royalty-free, and
>   non-exclusive license to reproduce,
>   adapt, modify, translate, publicly
>   perform, publicly display and
>   distribute Your Content through the
>   Service and as search results through
>   Google Services**. This license is
>   solely for the purpose of enabling
>   Google to operate the Service, to
>   promote the Service **(including through
>   public presentations)**, and to index
>   and **serve such content as search
>   results through Google Services**. If
>   you are unable or unwilling to provide
>   such a license to Your Content, **please
>   see the FAQ for information on
>   configuring your Maps API
>   Implementation to opt out.**
>
> 11.2 Brand Features License. You grant to Google a nontransferable,
>   nonexclusive license during the Term
>   to use Your Brand Features to
>   advertise that you are using the
>   Service.
>
> 11.3 Authority to Grant Licenses. You confirm and warrant to Google that you
>   have all the rights, power and
>   authority necessary to grant the above
>   licenses.

Anyway, keep in mind no such thing as a free lunch. At the end Google does search, and the more data they can get the better search they have.

Comment: With a license like that our client was just not willing to take a chance. Some of the data should not be searchable.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be submitted at all, it depends on how you are paring the XML file.

```
      GDownloadUrl("AMBest2bil50bil.xml", function(doc) {
        var xmlDoc = GXml.parse(doc);
        var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

        for (var i = 0; i "+name+"
Total Assets: "+formatCurrency(text)+""+address;
          var category = markers[i].getAttribute("category");
          // create the marker
          var marker = createMarker(point,name,html,category);
          GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            map.setCenter(point,10);
          });
          map.addOverlay(marker);
        }
```

That will parse my XML file and only manipulate the 'marker' tag.  You already have the info geocoded since you have the lat/long and I'd presume that the CDATA is for some type of popup/mouse over display.  I do not believe you will be passing any of that to Google.

Comment: Agreed,  the marker content is just being used by the client side javascript to display the infowindow.  Not sent to Google. +1

Comment: I disagree, see answer below...I don't know if it gets submitted or not, but the Terms you agree to allow them to reproduce that content.